# List of lists to iterables in itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools, combinatorics

I would like to use `itertools.product`.
The documentations specifies `itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)`.
For example this

```
for i in itertools.product([1,3,4],[2,3,6],[9,4]):
    print(i)
```

Outputs

```
(1, 2, 9)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 9)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 6, 9)
(1, 6, 4)
(3, 2, 9)
(3, 2, 4)
(3, 3, 9)
(3, 3, 4)
(3, 6, 9)
(3, 6, 4)
(4, 2, 9)
(4, 2, 4)
(4, 3, 9)
(4, 3, 4)
(4, 6, 9)
(4, 6, 4)
```

My problem is that I don't have a fixed number of such lists but a variables one as a list of lists (e.g. `[[1,3,4],[2,3,6],[9,4]]`).

I would like to transform this list of lists as iterables that I can pass to itertools.product.

**Bonus point.**
Acutally what I have isn't a list of lists but it is a dictionary which values are lists. So if I can avoid converting it to a list of lists it's even better.

Comment: This should be covered thoroughly on this site.  There are plenty of examples of using permutations and combinations from itertools to solve this problem if you search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### i think this is what you want:

```
import itertools

lists = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 6], [9, 4]]
for i in itertools.product(*lists):
    print(i)
```

#### Output:

```
(1, 2, 9)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 9)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 6, 9)
(1, 6, 4)
(3, 2, 9)
(3, 2, 4)
(3, 3, 9)
(3, 3, 4)
(3, 6, 9)
(3, 6, 4)
(4, 2, 9)
(4, 2, 4)
(4, 3, 9)
(4, 3, 4)
(4, 6, 9)
(4, 6, 4)
```